# Given an array of 'dogs', 'cats', and 'water', write a func. called separate, which returns a new array so the dogs are sep. from the cats by water

Tags: javascript

Make sure that cats always come first in the array.

Example: separate(['dog','cat','water','cat']) // ['cat', 'cat', 'water', 'dog'])

I'm new to creating functions and passing arguments into them so please forgive the obvious mistakes.

```
function separate (arr) {
let arr = ['dog','cat','water','cat'];
let result = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === 'dog') return 1;
  if (b === 'dog') return -1;
  else return a.localeCompare(b); // cat always at the beginning.
});

console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why does cat have to be ahead of dog? from what you want, I can't see that you want them to be sorted, since dog is after water. I know this is an example.

Comment: Sounds like a good homework assignment. What exactly is the problem you're facting?

Comment: What happens if there's more than one _water_? What happens if there's no dogs? No cats? No animals at all? No water?

Comment: @Phil, the question starts with "Given an array of 'dogs', 'cats', and 'water'," Why the OP decided to show code with two 'cats' is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store sorting indices and refer to those when determining sort order

```js
const sortIndex = new Map([
  [ "cat", 1 ],
  [ "water", 2 ],
  [ "dog", 3 ]
])

function separate(arr) {
  // create a copy of the array so as not to mutate the original
  return [...arr].sort((a, b) =>
    sortIndex.get(a) - sortIndex.get(b))
}

const arr = ["dog", "cat", "water", "cat"]

const t1 = performance.now()

const result = separate(arr)

const t2 = performance.now()

console.info(result)
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```